# How to decode utf-16 emoji surrogate pairs into uf8-8 and display them correctly in html?

Tags: javascript, xml, string, utf-8, utf-16

I have a **string** which contains **xml**. It has the following **substring**

```
<Subject>&amp;#55357;&amp;#56898;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56846;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56843;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56843;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56832;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56846;</subject>
```

I'm pulling the **xml** from a server and I need to display it to the user. I've noticed the ampersand has been escaped and there are utf-16 surrogate pairs. How do I ensure the emojis/emoticons are displayed correctly in a browser.

Currently I'm just getting these characters: �������������� instead of the actual emojis.

I'm looking for a simple way to fix this without any external libraries or any 3rd party code if possible just plain old javascript, html or css.

Comment: Possible help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187165/convert-55357-56911-to-emoji-in-html-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert UTF-16 code units including surrogates to a JavaScript string with `String.fromCharCode`. The following code snippet should give you an idea.

```js
var str = '&amp;#55357;&amp;#56898;ABC&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56846;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56843;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56838;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56843;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56832;&amp;#55357;&amp;#56846;';

// Regex matching either a surrogate or a character.
var re = /&amp;#(\d+);|([^&])/g;
var match;
var charCodes = [];

// Find successive matches
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  if (match[1] != null) {
    // Surrogate
    charCodes.push(match[1]);
  }
  else {
    // Unescaped character (assuming the code point is below 0x10000),
    charCodes.push(match[2].charCodeAt(0));
  }
}

// Create string from UTF-16 code units.
var result = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, charCodes);
console.log(result);
```