# How to send/convert html entity emojis into UTF-8 using PHP

Tags: php, html, email, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using the OneSignal/emoji-picker library to input emojis in a form and then submit that form to a PHP script which then sends the input via PHPMailer.

The emoji input coming from the form is in html entity format like so:

```
&#128516;&#128557;&#128516;
```

Then when sending this out it obviously is read and displayed literally as a string in e-mail clients rather than displaying the UTF-8 emojis images.

How do I convert the html entities into the UTF-8 that e-mail clients can understand?

I tried the built in PHP function `htmlentities()` the ouput is a strange format I've not seen before `ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜‚` doe's anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you tried `echo utf8_encode("&#128516;&#128557;&#128516;");`

Comment: this will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187165/convert-55357-56911-to-emoji-in-html-using-php

Comment: its working fine for me, just need to replace `$str = "&#128516;&#128557;&#128516";`

Comment: @devpro it doesn't work for me, the example given works but `&#128516;` doesn't. I noticed in the example there are only have 5 digits where my input has 6. I'm guessing this is the possible issue.

Comment: `$str = "&#128516;";` its also working